# Android Activity Hell - can A B C D E, become A C B ? Move to front and finish activities in between

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Can a backstack consisting of Activities A B C D E, become A C B ? Moving Activity B to the front and finishing certain activities in between.

Why not `clear top`? Well I still want Activity A to exist.

Insight appreciated? And yes I should be using a Conductor Controller or Fragment, but before re-writing the whole app I'd like to know if the Activity controller can accommodate.

Comment: you can easily get to A C D B. Getting rid of that D is a little more complex. I would possibly use `startActivityForResult`, and have a special result code to decide what to close.

Comment: @njzk2 my problem with that is activity D already RELIES on starting activity E with a result, and listening for its outcomes. So this makes adding an additional result from E that is supposed to kill D to be impossible, because it breaks the other case that D is already always listening for.

Comment: Can't you use FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT on B after you get the result in D?

Comment: @codeMagic possibly, since I can conditionally put something in the C's intent bundle to pass to D. But this still breaks the normal case for D where it already starts E expecting a certain result and request code.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you need but I mean D --> E (finish) --> D here finish and use the flag to bring B to the front

Comment: @codeMagic existing operations: D -- startActivityForResult(E, 100) -- E (finish) -- onActivityResult w/ requestCode 100 -- D.  D always already gets result 100. This is used for interoperability of D and E already, as D has a gui for relaunching E with modified data. So even with an additional flag in my new flow it would break onActivityResult. :(  I think I will just launch with cleartask and make ActivityB check to see if the backstack still exists or not and change its back behavior accordingly.